# "You gotta love xyz": What is the formal version?

Tags: formality

"You gotta love xyz" is an often a sarcastic (and colloquial) way of pointing out a preference/like for something. Is there a more formal way to express similar sarcasm when describing a preference/like?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "sarcasm" here. You may want to reword your question with an edit.

Comment: I also don't see exactly how "sarcasm" fits here. If you say *"You gotta love pussy!"* to someone, does that somehow become sarcastic or not, depending on the gender and sexual orientation of either/both of you?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Add in personal taste, and that’s far too many axes of confusion to chart out.  Best steer clear of that one. :)

Comment: Always the odd man out, I got your meaning right away. No need to ferret out a question for me! Go figure. Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the preference for something is only a **feigned** preference (which is often an element of irony and sarcasm), I suggest the following:

> "Don't you just *love* it when ***_*__*_*_** !"

Or, fleshed out,

> "Don't you just love it when some jerk swerves suddenly in front of you and into your lane without using a turn signal?"

Answer (score 1):

May be a better way can be,"**You are going to love xyz**".

"**You Gotta**" is also written as "**You got to...**"